# Importing dgn geometry into empty file geodatabase feature class?

Tags: fme-form, file-geodatabase, feature-class, dgn

I have an empty geodatabase in arcgis for certain domain application. It has several feature datasets each containing related feature classes. 
for example : feature dataset - NATURE,  it has a feature class  - TREEs

The geodatabase is empty.

Now i have features (corresponding to geodatabase) in a DGN drawing. My task is to import and load these features which are in the CAD drawing (.dgn file) to the corresponding features class in the geodatabase.

Can these kind of import and loading of data in database possible with FME. If yes how?

What information is required? I do not have any attribute information for features in .dgn file.

screenshot of dgn file. ( unique color and name)

[image]

---

Comment: Are the features in the DGN on separate layers?  Or do they have a unique colouring?  How are they defined in the DGN?  One thing you'll have to be careful of is DGNs can store multiple types of geometry in one layer, whereas, a fgdb can only store one type of geometry. When you load a DGN file you will get certain format attributes which you can expose such as layer name.  These can easily be filtered and directed to feature classes in a FGDB.

Comment: they are in unique colour and also have feature name. but how doi direct them to corresponding feature class in fgdb. Let me put some screenshot which may be helpful.

Comment: You'll have to prep the data a bit before you can get it into the geodatabase.  You may need to filter by igds_layer_name (I think that's the one) using a testfilter transformer.  You might also need to use a geometryfilter transformer.  Once you get the features you need, connect them to your FGDB writer.  How much experience with FME do you have?

Comment: i got FME only a week ago. I know it is difficult to guide me here. if you have any tutorial links or video relevant to my task please share. thanks !

Comment: Try this webinar by Safe: http://www.safe.com/webinar/microstation-dgn-how-to-integrate-cad-and-gis/